# logout link not working when on nav bar using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

My logout link is not working from the navigation bar; however, if I add the link on the home page, or if I go directly to the route (http://localhost/dico/public/logout) it works and the user is logged out.

When I review the page source code, I confirmed the href in the logout link is correct. If I click on the link from the source code, the user gets logged out.

ROUTE

```
Route::get('logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');
```

CONTROLLER

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class SessionsController extends Controller
 {
     public function __construct()
     {...}

     public function create()
     {...}

     public function store()
     {...}

     public function destroy()
     {
         auth()->logout();

         return redirect('/login');
     }
 }
```

THE VIEW

```
 <li><a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a></li>
```

I also tried

Logout

Comment: the user gets logged out and never redirect to /login?

Comment: When you click the link does it hit the `destroy` method?

Comment: Better to try with `php artisan serve`

Comment: Are you using Laravel auth scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function destroy()
 {
     Auth::logout();

     return redirect('/login');
 }
```

in controller

```
   use Auth;
```

Comment: It would help if your answer included some sort of description of how to use it and why it fixes the original question.

Comment: just use above code. in your function and add use Auth;  where you add model or some facades.

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

LIke this way can add in your controller

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you:

Need to change

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a></li>
```

**TO**

```
<li><a href="{{ url('logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a></li>
```

**OR**

```
<a href="{{ url('logout') }}">LOGOUT</a>
```

Comment: @AndresQuintero: Hope you get something from this answer, please check it

Answer (score -1):

```
     <a style="color: #2F4F4F" href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
         onclick="event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
       Logout <i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>

     </a>

   <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST"
       style="display: none;">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
   </form>
                                </li>
```

Try to use this intead